# Preserve equality with match expression

Tags: lean, lean4

How can I prove that the matched pattern is equal to the original argument?

For example, in the following function, what can I write instead of `sorry` to prove the equality?

```
def e1 (x: Option Nat): Nat :=
  match x with
  | none => 1
  | some y =>
    have : some y = x := sorry
    y+1
```

The only option I could come up with was using a pair with an equality proof, but that seems a bit too complex:

```
def e2 (x: Option Nat): Nat :=
  let x' := x
  have x'_eq: x' = x := rfl
  match x', x'_eq with
  | none, _ => 1
  | some y, y_eq =>
    have : some y = x := y_eq
    y+1
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for this is `match h : x with`, <s>no whitespace after `h` or `:`,</s> which will leave you with hypotheses of `h : x = none` and `h : x = some y` in each branch. There's [an open PR](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/pull/1015) to add this to the docs, it will probably be pulled in the next day or two.

Comment: Note: The syntax isn't whitespace sensitive anymore.

Answer (score 9):

In Lean 3, you can solve this using the following syntax:

```hs
def e1 (x : option ℕ) : ℕ :=
match _, rfl : ∀ y, y = x → _ with
| none, h := 1
| some y, h :=
  have some y = x := h,
  y+1
end
```

The `match x, y : T with` syntax means "generate a function of type `T` called `e1._match` or similar, and then replace this match expression with `e1._match x y`". `T` is usually therefore of the form `X → Y → _`, where `_` is the type of the values within the match expression.

Note that this is essentially the same as your solution, but the `match` expression lets us combine it all into one line.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that still easily allows recursion? I was using the alternative match notation (without the explicit `match` keyword or `:=`) since my function is recursively defined. I don't see how to do that with that alternative match syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is for Lean, but users of other languages might stumble over it as it is a quite common problem, so it might be useful to collect design patterns in all languages.

In Agda, the [inspect idiom](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/with-abstraction.html#the-inspect-idiom) is usually defined to create a singleton which also contains a witness that the matched expression is equal to the original expression. For built-in `Equality`, it can be defined like this:

```
data Singleton {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : Set a where
  _with≡_ : (y : A) → x ≡ y → Singleton x

inspect : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) → Singleton x
inspect x = x with≡ refl
```

Your example then can be implemented like this (using built-in `Nat` and `Maybe`):

```
e1 : Maybe Nat → Nat
e1 x with inspect x
... | nothing with≡ p = 1
... | just y  with≡ p = {! p : x ≡ just y !}
```

Comment: Note that the inspect idiom is built into Agda now, you don't need to define your own Singleton type and inspect function, you can just use the `in` keyword: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/with-abstraction.html#with-abstraction-equality